# C++ fstream is writing hex instead of string?

Tags: c++, fstream

I'm trying to download a file using `URLDownloadToFile()` which is working so far, however I'm having trouble with the callback function and writing the callback output wszStatusText to a file.

Here is the function that's giving the problem:

```
HRESULT DownloadStatus::OnProgress(ULONG ulProgress, ULONG ulProgressMax, ULONG ulStatusCode, LPCWSTR wszStatusText)
{
    fstream myfile;
    myfile.open("file.txt", ios::app);

    // this prints hex
    myfile << " StatusText: " << wszStatusText;
    myfile.close();

    // this prints the string properly
    MessageBox(NULL, wszStatusText, L"test", MB_OK);

    return S_OK;
}
```

The thing is that `MessageBox()` is showing the data properly...

**UPDATE**

After getting an exception error (using `wfstream`) I found out that the reason why it was giving me that because the first value of `wszStatusText` was NULL.

Comment: use `std::wfstream`.http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/wfstream/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a wide character C-string into a narrow character stream. There is no good automatic conversion for that, so you just get a pointer address.

Use a `std::wfstream` instead.

Comment: Ok, I've changed to `wfstream myfile`, (everything else is the same), now I get a Unhandled exception when I run (debug) it... am I missing something here?

Comment: @user5062925: That's a completely different problem. It really sounds like you need a mentor to step you through it. Is there a lab assistant or someone you can talk to?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I'm all on my own... I tried messing around with `wfstream` and it does work, however it doesn't with wszStatusText for some reason. I've posted the full code for the sake of clarity in my question.